# Load images from local filesystem as src property of image tag in silverlight out of browser application

Tags: c#, .net, silverlight-4.0

I have silverlight out of browser application and I'v placed some images in my my documents/images folder, my application has access to this folder, when I iterate through this folder, i can get pathes of all images, but when I try to bind this pathes to image tag src property in my app, it doesn't works, is there any way to solve this problem?

Comment: I think setting paths might only work for those that are relative to the application. Think about using `BitmapSource` as the source instead.